# Ubuntu without GUI

Tags: linux, ubuntu, command-line

I use Ubuntu in a VM on my MacBook Pro for deep learning. But that causes a wastage of my CPU (as it's in a VM PLUS with a GUI). All I do is SSH into the VM, as I never use the GUI and proceed with my work.

So my problem is that deep learning already requires a lot of compute power, which is lost as VirtualBox allows using only half of system resources. Emphasis on GUI taking up resources.

Is there any distro in your mind, from the Debian tree, which comes with the `apt` package manager (cause at this point I don't wanna tinker with another distro and their compatibility with TensorFlow)? All I want is the Ubuntu shell.

All I want is something similar to Windows Sub-system for Linux.

Or if you could guide me on how to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox without a GUI.

More on why I don't use TensorFlow in macOS itself in comments.

Comment: I work with other python pkgs/libs which need the latest stable version of python to work. Whereas, tensorflow needs a version between 3.4 & 3.6, as of writing this. So I use a VM instead.

I could use a virtualenv instead but I find am VM more accessible over a virtual environment, no emphasis on virtual. ;)

Answer (score 2):

For a minimal Debian-based CLI setup I would look into either the minimal Network Installation (netinst) Debian image or Ubuntu Server, which is a command-line only version of the distro with some common server packages included.

The Debian netinst image installs a minimal system and allows you to install more packages yourself over the network. The Ubuntu Server image will have more packages included in a default install so it is less minimal, but will probably take less time to set up depending on what you are doing. With both you'll just need to enable sshd and any other services or packages you need for your software.

Answer (score 1):

> Or if you could guide me on how to install Ubuntu on VirtualBox without a GUI.

Just install the [Ubuntu Server](https://ubuntu.com/server) edition in VirtualBox, and enable `sshd` by default. Then one can simply connect via ssh in the terminal.

One could also consider using [Vagrant](https://www.vagrantup.com) to automate your virtual machine setup.

Comment: I already AM using Ubuntu server edition for until I find a solution. I know I can ssh into the VM from my mac, but I also sometimes need a pictorial representation (provided by matplotlib) which is neither available by ssh-ing into Ubuntu desktop edition nor directly running my code in the Ubuntu Server VM.